# Changing the location of a control on a windows form programatically using VB.net?

Tags: vb.net

I need to change the location property of label1 from (50, 50) to (50, 70) when Button1 is clicked. This should be easy, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What are you trying? I find the easiest thing to do is set the Top and Left properties individually:

```
label1.Left = 50;
label1.Top = 70;
```

Setting Location.X and Location.Y will probably result in a compile-time error, because Location is of type "Point", a value type.

Comment: Setting Location.X and Location.Y will result in a compile-time error.

Answer (score 27):

You can also do it this way:

```
label1.Location = new Point(x,y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do like this.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Location = New Point(50, 70)
End Sub
```

Yes just copy & paste.