# Move all Button objects down 100px on CheckBox tick?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to move a set of 30 buttons downwards 100px when a textbox is ticked (and then back to their origins when the box is unticked). This is to provide room for some labels below the buttons if the user requires it... like the "show hints" box here: http://www.phonemicchart.com/

I have the following code:

```
    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then

        Button5.Location = New Point(100, 100)
        Label1.Visible = False
    Else
        Button5.Location = New Point(300, 300)
        Label1.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is the New Point() function. The new point I would like is -100px relative to origin, and then for the Else statement for it to be Button5.Location = Origin.

What commands can I use to achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps this would be easier with a [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another idea...put all the buttons inside a `Panel`, then changed the `.Top` property of it to move everything inside it.

```
  Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                                       ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then
      Panel1.Top += 100
    Else
      Panel1.Top -= 100
    End If
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### use Left and Top instead as in:

[Changing the location of a control on a windows form programatically using VB.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535087/changing-the-location-of-a-control-on-a-windows-form-programatically-using-vb-ne)

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then

        Button5.Top = 100
        Button5.Left = 100
        Label1.Visible = False
    Else
        Button5.Top = 300
        Button5.Left = 300
        Label1.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the controls owned by your container, and as offered by mfarid, you can use the Top property

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
Dim ctrl As Control
For Each ctrl In container.Controls
  If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then  
    ctrl.Top += 100
  ElseIf
    ctrl.Top -= 100
  End If
Next
EndSub
```