# About My.Controls in Visual Basic 2012

Tags: vb.net

So I have a picturebox that I want to move around. If I refer to it in this way

```
Dim x,y as integer
Dim boxname as string = "picturebox1"
x = 10
y = 10
Me.Controls(boxname).Location = New Point(x,y)
```

I got error. How can I call a control indirectly through variable?

Comment: Try [.top and .left](http://stackoverflow.com/a/535108/3585500)

Comment: If the error message a secret?  Shall we guess what error to fix?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include it. The error is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @ourmandave I believe the problem is at the Me.Controls usage rather than the box's location command.

Answer (score 0):

`Me.Controls` means look for the control *directly* in the Controls() collection of the **Form itself** (because "Me" is referencing the Form).  If the PictureBox is located in a **different** containter, like a Panel or GroupBox, then it will not be found.  Change "Me" to the name of the correct container, such as "Panel1" or "GroupBox1":

```
Panel1.Controls(boxname).Location = New Point(x,y)
```

If you need a solution that works without specifying the correct container, then **search** for it like this:

```
Dim matches() As Control = Me.Controls.Find(boxname, True)
If matches.Length > 0 AndAlso TypeOf matches(0) Is PictureBox Then
    Dim pb As PictureBox = DirectCast(matches(0), PictureBox)
    pb.Location = New Point(x,y)
End If
```